# can't find IIS 7.5 after resetting the user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localhost, iis-7.5

This may be the dumbest question but I have a small problem I am using windows7 and recently I had an issue with my outlook as a result I had to recreate my profile on windows.
since that moment I can't see IIS7.5[image: search in start]

I have also tried to use control pannel add windwos feature and I can only find IIS6 [image: windows feature image]

The strange thing about this is that I have files hosted in IIS7.5 and when I browse to the web Url(I use custom host) I can go there but creating a new website is impossible as I can't go to IIS 7.5
also browsing to Localhost gives me the indication that IIS7 is installed
[image: localhost]

What can I do?

I have tried also using the script from Microsoft site [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725762.aspx) but that wasn't successful and I am wondering what to do really.

also when I type Localhost on any browser I get the big image with IIS7 on it what suggest it is installed.

Just today using manage mycomputer(Win 7), service and application  and restarted the IIS Admin service and now I can see the IIS7.5 as per the [image: iis image], but not sure why I can't see it in the accessories on when I do a search for IIS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1038) IIS 7.5 express from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1038)

Comment: I guess I could have done that but as I said IIS 7.5 was there but there was no way to get into it to create new websites or change existing ones etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post in super user forum discussing about the posted issue. 
https://superuser.com/questions/752946/iis-manager-disappeared-from-start-menu-and-administrative-tools
Copied from there:

```
Your system is behaving in an abnormal manner, and it is hard to diagnose that error. It seems like it is caused by some system corruption.

The following tools can diagnose and fix errors in Windows :

sfc /scannow
Scans the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replaces incorrect corrupted, changed/modified, or damaged versions with the correct versions if possible.

System Update Readiness Tool for Windows
Scans for Windows corruption errors that prevent Windows updates and service packs from installing.

Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor
Scans hardware, devices, and installed programs for known compatibility issues, giving guidance on how to resolve potential issues found, and recommends what to do.

Windows Update fixit or Reset Windows Update components
then try again to turn off the IIS Windows feature, reboot, reinstall, reboot.

Full antivirus scan by your current product and in addition at least Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.

If running these tools gives no hint as to the problem, the next step is a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7, which fixes the current installation of Windows while preserving user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.

The last resort, to reinstall Windows from scratch, is not to be taken lightly unless really necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks I got your message after I had tried to restart the process and I can't say if that can work or not